# "Can not launch AVD in emulator" : Emulator startup fails : Heap size issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, size, android-virtual-device, heap-memory

I have just updated Android SDK tools to latest one and created new AVD with android v6.0.

I am getting error as attached here [image]

Emulator settings are as shown in this attached image

[image]

Is someone facing same issue ?

Comment: Give VM heap to 4000 and restart the avd

Comment: should be ok with those settings -- in AVD manager click on the arrow down on the right side of the VM (Actions) and choose (view details) paste the results in your Q to have a look -- you can try rebooting the PC, maybe that will help

Answer (score 1):

> To maintain a functional multi-tasking environment, Android sets a
>   hard limit on the heap size for each app. The exact heap size limit
>   varies between devices based on how much RAM the device has available
>   overall.

So, You should Increase your **VM Heap Size** & **`Restart`** .Hope this helps .

Please check my **settings** .

[image]